# Mutex in RTOSes in this specific situation

Tags: cortex-m

Consider the following codes:

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 First Thread 
 *---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void Thread1 (void const *argument) 
{
    for (;;) 
    {
        osMutexWait(mutex, osWaitForever); 
                Thread1_Functions;
        osMutexRelease(mutex);  
    }
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Second Thread  
 *---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void Thread2 (void const *argument) 
{
    for(;;)
    {
        osMutexWait(mutex, osWaitForever);
                Thread2_Functions;
        osMutexRelease(mutex);
    }
}
```

As far as I've noticed from RTOS's scheduling ,RTOS assign a specific time to each task and after this time is over,it switches to the other task.
Then in this specific time,inside task's infinite loop ,maybe loop is repeated several times until task's specific time finished.
Assume task is finished in less than of it's time's half,then it has a time to fully run this task once again :
in last line after releasing mutex , then it will achieve mutex before than task2 for second time,Am I true ?
assume timer tick occur when MCU run Thread1_Functions for second time,then task2 cant run because mutex owned by task1, RTOS run task 1 again and if timer tick occur every time in the Thread1_Functions, then task2 has no chance to running,Am I true ?

Comment: This depends entirely on whether your scheduler is "fair". Various schedulers are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the specific RTOS implementation. There are various mutex and scheduler schemes around, so a general answer is quite difficult, as anything might happen, so you might be correct for a specific RTOS.

This is what I would expect:

1. Task 1 locks mutex
2. System tick occurs and switches to Task 2
3. Task 2 runs until it wants to lock the mutex (already locked by Task 1)
4. Task 2 gets stalled, Task 1 gets priority to run until it releases the mutex
5. Task 1 runs until it releases the mutex, upon releasing it, the RTOS switches back to Task 2
6. Task 2 locks the mutex
7. System tick occurs and switches to Task 1
8. Task 1 runs until it wants to lock the mutex (already locked by Task 2)
9. Task 1 gets stalled, Task 2 gets priority to run until it releases the mutex
10. ... (You see the pattern by now, hopefully)

So even then task 2 will run eventually.

If you have to lock a mutex for a time so long that it gets into the region of the system tick, I'd take a step back and think about my architecture and system design and look for points where it can be improved.

But to be sure on what happens, you have to read the manual for the RTOS you are using.